# What is the difference between a flat and curved capo?

Tags: guitar, capos

I want to buy a capo... What is the difference between a [flat](http://accessories.musiciansfriend.com/product/Dunlop-Trigger-Flat-Guitar-Capo?sku=361505) and a [curved](http://accessories.musiciansfriend.com/product/Dunlop-Trigger-Curved-Guitar-Capo?sku=361506) capo? Can I use either for both an electric and acoustic guitar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not much. If it is curved too much then obviously it won't work as well on a flat neck. A curved capo is going to work better on low radius necks such as a strat and only near the nut.

Get a flat one and you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: Can't really authoritatively comment on the truth of that, but the curve relates to the radius of the fretboard. Classical guitars tend to have very flat, very wide fretboards and thus a flat capo would be necessary, while most steel-string acoustics and electrics have curved fretboards which are more fitting to the arch of the fingers. So it seems like a curved one would be the natural for the guitars bluevoodoo1 is talking about. But if you talk to the guitar shop folks, they should let you test before you buy.